# Navigation menu A Href doesn't work when back to directory try?

Tags: php, html, css

I tried to make the navigation menu. I took his menu file using code "include" in my index.php file.

When I select the guitar work. but when re-pressing the home button. can not go back to the index or home? guitar.php files are in direcorty pages / guitar.php.

Why this can not go back to the index directly? please help me. Thank you

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php" >Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="pages/guitar.php">Guitars</a>
     <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Guitar Acoustics</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Guitar Electirs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Guitar Amplifiers</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Guitar Effects</a></li>
     
    </ul>
   
   </ul>
```

above is the code in the file navigation menu.

```html
<?php
require_once "layout/header.php"; 
include ("layout/nav.php");
require_once "layout/aside.php";?>
?>
```

above is the code in file index.php, and pages/guitar.php.
Thanks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your links are relative, which means they'll just replace the "xxx.php" bit at the end of your URL, so when you go to "pages/guitar.php" your home link becomes "pages/index.php".

Make them start with a `/` and they'll be relative to your domain, eg. if your site is `mydomain.com`, your homepage becomes `mydomain.com/index.php` and the guitars page is `mydomain.com/pages/guitar.php`.

```
<a href="/index.php">Home</a>
<a href="/pages/guitar.php">Guitars</a>
```

If gets a shade more complicated if your site isn't at the root of your domain. For example, if your homepage is actually at `mydomain.com/guitar-site/index.php` then you'll need to add the `/guitar-site` to the front of the URLs as well, so the link goes to the right place:

```
<a href="/guitar-site/index.php">Home</a>
<a href="/guitar-site/pages/guitar.php">Guitars</a>
```

Comment: thank u, the problem in thr root of domain. change to <a href="/mysite/index.php">Home</a>
<a href="/mysite/pages/guitar.php">Guitars</a> and worked :)

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing `include ("layout/nav.php");` with `header("location:layout/nav.php");`

Comment: This will redirect you to the `layout/nav.php` file, and show it without the header, aside and content. You probably don't want that